# mod_rewrite: how to stop it after the first match?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP application that uses GET variables to determine language, that is:

```
http://example.com/?lang=en
```

And I'm writing a mod_rewrite rule so that people can access it using SEO friendly URLs:

```
http://example.com/en/
```

My .htaccess looks like this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2} /test.php?lang=$0 [L]
```

(The test.php thing is just a test, not the name of my real app).

But when I access:

```
http://example.com/fr/blabla
```

What I get in my rewrite_log is the following:

```
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b8ce58/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/example/fr -> /var/www/html/example/fr/blabla
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b8ce58/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/example/fr/blabla -> fr/blabla
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b8ce58/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] applying pattern '^[a-z]{2}' to uri 'fr/blabla'
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b8ce58/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] rewrite 'fr/blabla' -> '/test.php?lang=fr'
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b8ce58/initial] (3) split uri=/test.php?lang=fr -> uri=/test.php, args=lang=fr
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b8ce58/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] internal redirect with /test.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b92310/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/example/test.php -> test.php
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b92310/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] applying pattern '^[a-z]{2}' to uri 'test.php'
192.168.172.1 - - [24/Feb/2015:16:30:10 +0100] [example.com/sid#896a010][rid#8b92310/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/example/] pass through /var/www/html/example/test.php
```

What I don't understand is why, after the first match (4th line in the log), mod_rewrite keeps matching and redirecting again and again. I found several people posting similar questions here, and as a result of their answers, I tried adding the `RewriteCond` rule, but mod_rewrite seems to ignore it (yes, test.php does exist in my filesystem). What's going on?

EDIT: forgot to mention. The server I'm testing this on is an Apache 2.2.3.

EDIT: nevermind. It was a typo in my test.php, which was preventing it from being executed correctly (can you add here one of those "eyeroll" or "embarrassed" emojis?)

Comment: Your rewrite log output doesn’t show any sign of your RewriteCond being in place when it was created. Please show actual log output with the RewriteCond in place.

Comment: Well, I can assure you that the RewriteCond has been there all along. In fact, I tried restarting Apache again, just in case, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop after first rewrite you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2} test.php?lang=$0 [L,QSA]
```

`%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is internal variable that is set to 200 after first rewrite by Apache.

However `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should stop rewrite loop after first rewrite if `test.php` is **a valid file**.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work (the log is exactly the same than before). My Apache server is 2.2.3. Does that have any influence?

Comment: It definitely works, don't rely on interpretation of rewrite logs. If it keeps rewriting then you will get infinite loop otherwise and multiple times `lang=` parameter.

Comment: What I mean by "doesn't work" is that my test.php file has some static HTML text, and then a simple PHP instruction that prints the value of $_GET['lang']. If it worked, it should show the static text and then print "fr" in the example above, and yet all I get is a blank screen. (Also, look at the penultimate line in the log: it's applying the regex to the already-redirected URL again).

Comment: Well to test it separately create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then change your above rule to `RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/?$ info.php?lang=$0 [L,QSA]` and then see what you get in browser.